# DCount with 2 criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am using `DCount` to help display an error message if the data signals an error.  I have it working with one criteria where a number is equal to another number.  Now I wanted to add another criteria in there where another field, `ReturnDate` (this field is Text not Date/Time) is equal to a hyphen (-).
I'm just not really sure how to format it.  I have this:

```
If DCount("*", "CrewTable", "KitNumber=" & _
  Me.AssignKit.Value And "ReturnDate=" & _
  "-") > 0 Then
  Cancel = True
  MsgBox "Kit is already assigned!"
  AssignKit = ""
  AssignKit.SetFocus
Else
...
```

The error pops up with a 'Type Mistmatch' and the debugger highlights the whole statment from 'If -> Then' and has an error pointing to the line with the hyphen in the quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
If DCount("*", "CrewTable", "ReturnDate='-' AND KitNumber=" & _
          Me.AssignKit.Value) > 0 Then
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easier to troubleshoot `DCount` errors when you store its *Criteria* option in a string variable.

```
Dim strCriteria As String
strCriteria = "ReturnDate='-' AND KitNumber=" & Me.AssignKit.Value
Debug.Print strCriteria
If DCount("*", "CrewTable", strCriteria) > 0 Then
```

If you had used this approach, Access would have alerted you to the fact that the original code which built the *Criteria* string was invalid.  That should make it clearer that the problem wasn't due to the `If` condition, and it wasn't *exactly* a `DCount` problem either ... it was a problem with string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.AssignKit.Value & " And ReturnDate=" & _
```

Comment: This gives me a Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression