# DCount syntax error

Tags: vba, ms-access

Why does `DCOUNT` cause a syntax error?

```
DCount("[Commercial_name] + [Producer] + [Start_date]", "[Cleaning product]", "[Commercial_name] = '" & Me.PP.Value & "' AND [Producer] = '" & Me.PR.Value & "' AND [Start_date] = '" & Me.Rdate.Value & "'")
```

On the VBA page is all on one line

Comment: The first argument is expected to be an expression that defines the specific field you want to count records. You've given a concatenation of 3 fields.

Comment: Use this example for how to do a Dcount of multiple fields: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839572/dcount-with-2-criteria

Answer (score 0):

It's the date:

```
DCount("*", "[Cleaning product]", "[Commercial_name] = '" & Me!PP.Value & "' And [Producer] = '" & Me!PR.Value & "' And [Start_date] = #" & Format(Me!Rdate.Value, 'yyyy\/mm\/dd') & "#")
```